# ProgressDialog is not updating in Async task

Tags: android

Could anyone explain why my progress dialog is not updating when my async task is running?
The progress dialog appears, but the percentage indicator does not increase at all.
Is there something obvious here?

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, Long> {
        private ProgressDialog mProgress;

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(HelloActivity.this);
            mProgress.setMessage("Fetching Image data..");
            mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgress.setCancelable(false);
            //mProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgress.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... urls) {

            long totalSize = 0;

            for(int i=0; i < dbLinks.size(); i++){

                try {
                    ....doe some stuff here
                    publishProgress((i/dbLinks.size()) * 100);
                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return totalSize;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            mProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

            mProgress.dismiss();
            //use totalsize if necessary
            Intent intentFB = new Intent(HelloActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
            intentFB.putExtra("key", dbURLs);
            startActivity(intentFB);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer math.

```
(i/dbLinks.size()) * 100
```

`i/dbLinks.size()` will be always 0 and multiplying it by 100 doesn't change it.

To fix it, consider setting progress bar max to `dbLinks.size()` and publish `i` as progress.

Comment: Thanks this looks like the issue - I will test and if it works I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting the exception in your doInBackground method ,as i check sample demo it is working fine.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute()
    {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgress.setMessage("Fetching Image data..");
        mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        //mProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgress.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... progress) {

        long totalSize = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){

            try {

                publishProgress(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return totalSize;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        mProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

        mProgress.dismiss();
    }
}
```